# extract value from XML file and navigate it to its corresponding URL using MVC (i dunno how to navigate it to its particular URL.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an XML file with several environment names and corresponding URL to the environment name. 
Requirement is:
1. display the environment names in a dropdownlist 
2. select any environment name in dropdownlist.
3. Click Navigate link below dropdown button.
4. The page should be navigated to particular URL, which the environment name belongs to.

EX: (from XML File)

I want to fetch "name" & "LMHost" .

I completed upto creating dropdownlist. Binding environment name inside dropdownlist. But i dunno how to navigate it to particular URL.

**My Controller Code**

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> envGroups = from xmlDoc in xDoc.Descendants().Elements("environment")
                                                      select xmlDoc;
                    model.EnvironmentName = from envName in envGroups.Attributes("name")
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = envName.Value,
                                                Value = envName.Value.ToString(),
                                               Selected = (envName.Equals(envName))
                                            };
                    return View(model);
```

**View Code**

```
    <%=Html.DropDownList("EnvironmentName", new SelectList      (Model.EnvironmentName, "Value" , "Text")) %>
```

**Model Code**

public IEnumerable _environmentName;

```
    [DisplayName("EnvironmentName")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnvironmentName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_environmentName == null)
                _environmentName = new List<SelectListItem>();
            return _environmentName;
        }

        set { _environmentName = value; }
    }
```

Kindly help me. I find difficult to navigate the environment names to its particular URL

Comment: If you have the url I would recommend using jquery window.location = url

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, window.location will work

Include jquery on your page, and add a button or anchor to your page with the onclick action:

```
    window.location=$('#EnvironmentName').val();
```

You can prefix/suffix the location to create the correct path e.g.:

```
    window.location='http://yoursitepath/' +  $('#EnvironmentName').val() + '.html';
```